# Use cases for IdentityHashMap

Tags: java

Could anyone please tell what are the important use cases of `IdentityHashMap`?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The [documentations](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html) says:

> A typical use of this class is
>   topology-preserving object graph
>   transformations, such as serialization
>   or deep-copying. To perform such a
>   transformation, a program must
>   maintain a "node table" that keeps
>   track of all the object references
>   that have already been processed. The
>   node table must not equate distinct
>   objects even if they happen to be
>   equal. Another typical use of this
>   class is to maintain proxy objects.
>   For example, a debugging facility
>   might wish to maintain a proxy object
>   for each object in the program being
>   debugged.

Comment: I'm coming from the documentation, looking for an explanation on SO

Answer (score 41):

Whenever you want your keys not to be compared by `equals` but by `==` you would use an IdentityHashMap. This can be very useful if you're doing a lot of reference-handling but it's limited to very special cases only.

Comment: The behavior of the comparison is the ticket here. I have used "Identity" HashMaps for storing meta-data that should be associated with a particular object. The value equality of the objects possibly being the same. However, care must be taken to ensure the original is preserved as long as the [direct] lookup is required -- and care must be taken to avoiding "leaking" memory.

Comment: Also, because the identity invariant (o == o => true, for any o), IdentityHashMap can be used *even if the key objects are mutated*. But you aren't using mutable keys... are you? (Perhaps I should go sit in a corner and cry.)

Answer (score 27):

One case where you can use IdentityHashMap is if your keys are Class objects. This is about 33% faster than HashMap for gets! It probably uses less memory too.

Comment: Do you have any source/benchmark to back that claim?

Comment: @DineshBabu Nothing really conclusive. There's [this](http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=21395.0) but of course microbenchmarks vary by JVM, map size, hash code quality, equals implementations, phase of the moon, etc. IdentityHashMap avoids Entry objects (has GC impact) and uses == for comparison, so is expected to perform a bit better.

You might like my [cuckoo map](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/ObjectMap.java), which has seen widespread usage in libgdx and Kryo. There are a number of other maps in the same package, including IdentityMap.

Answer (score 25):

You can also use the `IdentityHashMap` as a *general purpose map* **if** you can make sure the objects you use as keys will be equal *if and only if* their references are equal.

To what gain? Obviously it will be *faster* and will use less memory than using implementations like `HashMap` or `TreeMap`.

---

**Actually, there are quite a lot of cases when this stands. For example:**

- `Enum`s. Although for enums there is even a better alternative: [`EnumMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html)
- `Class` objects. They are also comparable by reference.
- Interned `String`s. Either by specifying them as *literals* or calling `String.intern()` on them.
- Cached instances. Some classes provide caching of their instances. For example quoting from the javadoc of [`Integer.valueOf(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf-int-):

> This method will always cache values in the range -128 to 127, inclusive...
>
> Certain libraries/frameworks will manage exactly one instance of ceratin types, for example Spring beans.
>
> Singleton types.  If you use istances of types that are built with the *Singleton* pattern, you can also be sure that (at the most) one instance exists from them and therefore reference equality test will qualify for equality test.
>
> Any other type where you explicitly take care of using only the same references for accessing values that were used to putting values into the map.
>
> ---

**To demonstrate the last point:**

```
Map<Object, String> m = new IdentityHashMap<>();

// Any keys, we keep their references
Object[] keys = { "strkey", new Object(), new Integer(1234567) };

for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++)
    m.put(keys[i], "Key #" + i);

// We query values from map by the same references:
for (Object key : keys)
    System.out.println(key + ": " + m.get(key));
```

Output will be, as expected (because we used the same `Object` references to query values from the map):

```
strkey: Key #0
java.lang.Object@1c29bfd: Key #1
1234567: Key #2
```

Answer (score 19):

HashMap creates Entry objects every time you add an object, which can put a lot of stress on the GC when you've got lots of objects. In a HashMap with 1,000 objects or more, you'll end up using a good portion of your CPU just having the GC clean up entries (in situations like pathfinding or other one-shot collections that are created and then cleaned up). IdentityHashMap doesn't have this problem, so will end up being significantly faster.

See a benchmark here: [http://www.javagaming.org/index.php/topic,21395.0/topicseen.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20101014202852/http://www.javagaming.org/index.php/topic,21395.0/topicseen.html)

Answer (score 13):

This is a practical experience from me:

IdentityHashMap leaves a much smaller memory footprint compared to HashMap for large cardinalities.

Answer (score 5):

One important case is where you are dealing with reference types (as opposed to values) and you really want the correct result. Malicious objects can have overridden `hashCode` and `equals` methods getting up to all sorts of mischief. Unfortunately, it's not used as often as it should be. If the interface types you are dealing with don't override `hashCode` and `equals`, you should typically go for `IdentityHashMap`.