# Practical use of IdentityHashMap in Java 6

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use cases for IdentityHashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838528/use-cases-for-identityhashmap)

What could be a practical use of the IdentityHashMap introduced in Java 5?

Comment: I think this question has been asked before... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/838528/use-cases-for-identity-hashmap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For adding dynamic fields to objects.

Some language directly support dynamic fields: anybody can add any field to any object any time.

This is handy when you want to associate some information to objects, unforseenable by object designer.

Java doesn't have real dynamic field. We can simulate it by using an identity map to associate an object to some information of some kind.

`WeakHashMap` is better for the purpose; it is an identity map too, and it doesn't add additional strong reference to the object. So it is much closer to the dynamic field concept.

Concurrency is the remaining problem. If two threads accessing the same dynamic field of two different objects, there shouldn't be dependencies among two threads. We can solve it by some kind of concurrent weak hashmap. However the performance isn't ideal compared to normal field access.

Think about `java.lang.ThreadLocal`, adding dynamic field to threads; and `java.lang.ClassValue`, adding dynamic field to classes. They aren't strictly necessary - we can achieve the same thing with concurrent weak maps. They exist for performance reason. JDK can "hack" into Thread/Class to add supports to achieve faster lookup.

Comment: Abover it states that `WeakHashMap` "is an identity map too". This isn't the case - in fact in bug [4500542](http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=4500542) in the Java bugs DB they acknowledge that it probably should have been one but isn't. For a weak identity hashmap see the javadoc for the Guava MapMaper class (the bit about `new MapMaker().weakKeys().makeMap()`).

Comment: I suggest you edit your Answer to fix the flaw shown in the Comment by Hawkins.

Answer (score 8):

Have a look at the [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html) :-)

> A typical use of this class is topology-preserving object graph
>   transformations, such as serialization or deep-copying. To perform
>   such a transformation, a program must maintain a "node table" that
>   keeps track of all the object references that have already been
>   processed. The node table must not equate distinct objects even if
>   they happen to be equal. Another typical use of this class is to
>   maintain proxy objects. For example, a debugging facility might wish
>   to maintain a proxy object for each object in the program being
>   debugged.

On a side note: it's available since version 1.4, not Java 5 or 6...

Answer (score 2):

When serializing mutable objects you want to keep track of the objects you have serialized and their reference id. You cannot use equality as you cannot trust mutable objects to use identity checks for equals and to not change. e.g. Date is mutable and equals compares contents.

Answer (score 0):

Used rarely. [It implements Map interface but used in rare cases wherein reference-equality semantics are required.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html)