# Use case for method , System.identityHashCode(Object x)

Tags: java

I read javadoc of this JAVA API method, `System.identityHashCode(Object x)` and not able to understand a typical use case of this method. Classes that need `hashCode()` are recommended to have overridden `hashCode()` method of their own so what is the purpose of this method if Object class already has default `hashCode()`?

Comment: Useful in an [`IdentityHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html) for example.

Comment: I agree with @BoristheSpider.  It seems it exists primarily for libraries which expect the default `hashCode()` method.  Put another way, there could be instances where a user overrides `hashCode()` in such a way which would break another library which expected certain behavior in the hash code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose that class C extends class B and class B overrides `hashCode` and `equals`.

Now suppose that for class C, you wish to use the default implementation of `hashCode` and `equals` as implemented in the `Object` class. Normally you don't want to do that, but suppose that each instance of the `C` class should be a unique key in some `HashMap`.

You can write :

```
public class C extends B
{
    @Override
    public int hashCode ()
    {
        return System.identityHashCode(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals (Object other)
    {
        return this == other;
    }
}
```

Similarly, if B override's `toString` and you want C's toString to have the default implementation of the Object class, you can write in C :

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(System.identityHashCode(this));
}
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen But if the super class of C (B) overrides hashCode, C will have B's implementation of hashCode. C won't have access to the default implementation of Object's hashCode in this case.

Comment: I upvoted your answer...but an example showing an actual Java library which did something like this would have made for an even jucier answer ^ ^

Answer (score 1):

There aren't a lot of use cases. It's primarily useful if for some reason you have a collection of objects, and only care about their object identities. This is really rare. One example is [IdentityHashMap](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/IdentityHashMap.java) (like @Boris says). It would actually be fine to just use `hashCode` of the objects for such hash map, but using identity hash would theoretically be faster, because it can avoid "collisions" between objects that are logically `equal` but aren't the same object (it also allows avoiding of badly implemented hash functions, I guess).

There aren't a lot of use case for such collections, either. You can see use cases for IdentityHashMap here: [Practical use of IdentityHashMap in Java 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667868/practical-use-of-identityhashmap-in-java-6)

Comment: Thanks for bringing in IdentityHashMap use cases in context, both seem to go together.

Answer (score -1):

Just one difference, if the Object given is **null** this Method gives **0**.

**Example 1:**

obj.hasCode();

*This code throws nullPointerException if the obj is null.*

**Example 2:**

System.identityHashCode(obj);

*This method return 0 and doesn't throw an exception cause it checks for null. Also it gives the HashCode that the default hashCode method would return even if you overrides it*

Did this answer help you?

Comment: And if the `obj` has overriden its `hashCode` method? Then the two are not even close to equivalent.