# Can somebody tell me the practical use of IdentityHashMap in java?

Tags: java

I know the concept of IdentityHashMap in java, but I have never seen its use till now. Can somebody explain me the real use or some real situation where we have to use IdentiyHashMap in java.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/838528/use-cases-for-identityhashmap

Comment: Possibly during object graph traversal, use it to make sure you don't visit/process the same object on the heap more than once.

Comment: I have visited this link earlier but still I do not get any appropriate use. Every object in java has a particular use, I just want to know in which situation we have to use IdentityHashMap.

Answer (score 2):

There are times when you want hashmap-like behavior (associating data with a key), but where the key has to be to a specific copy of the object rather than the object's value. That's what IdentityHashMap does for you.

For example, I've used it in the XSLT compiler to keep track of transient context information which had to be associated with a particular node in the parse tree. There might be a node elsewhere in the tree which had the same value, and hence would have the same hashcode and compare as equal, but the context it appeared in would be different so I needed to be able to look them up separately.

Basically: Yes, there are cases where it's useful. You may never run into them, but they're just common enough that it was worth including in the library rather than forcing those of us who do need it to reinvent it every time.